# Android listview dynamically change wallpaper

Tags: android

I am developing an application where there is one option provided for changing the wallpaper of chat window .
I have used listview for chat window and i want help how can i change its background wallpaper on clicking the "change wallpaper" setting.
I have done code to goto gallery and fetching the path from there.
Just want to know how to change listview background wallpaper.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this comes to mind:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
listView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.mynewbackground);
```

just make sure you replace R.id.listviewid with the id (set in xml) of your list view.

```
android:id="@+id/listviewid"
```

And replace R.id.mynewbackground with the resource id of your new background.

Comment: You will also need to set android:cacheColorHint to #00000000 if you're using images to avoid the background flickering to black every time the user scrolls.